# Where BIND9 saves its cache?

Tags: bind, apt, ubuntu-12.04, rndc

On Ubuntu 12.04 I installed BIND9 via `apt-get install`.

I configure the server in a very simple way and it works in name resolution.
Now I'm curious to read (if it's possible) its cache.

Reading the `rndc` manpage I tried to use the `rndc flush view` command, but it says

> rndc: `flush` failed: not found

while if I run simply `rndc flush` it works.

So, first of all, where I can find the BIND9 cache file?

And then, why `rndc flush view` fails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to be asking two different questions.

For the first, the cache is held only in RAM. However you can view it with `rndc dumpdb -cache` which will be saved (on Debian and Ubuntu) by default to `/var/cache/bind/`.

For the second, I think that perhaps you don't know what a view is with regard to bind.

A view is an alternate zone presented to a subset of clients. For example, if you have a private and public network you might create a public only view of your zone for external clients while internal clients will have a view for public and private networks. You can only flush a named view that is configured in `named.conf` (or any included files).

A view is not the same thing as a zone, and  you can't individually flush zones.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But after I run `rndc dumpdb --cache` I can't find the file in `/var/cache/bind`. This folder contains managed-keys.bind and managed-keys.bind.jnl

Comment: Look in `/etc/bind/*` for the `directory` directive. This will be the location where it gets saved. And the user `bind` must have write permission for that directory.

Comment: I know this is an OT, but I have `directory "/etc/bind/";` and I also run `chown root.bind /etc/bind/`, but the `dumpdb` file doesn't yet exist.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the group permission is `+w` for `/etc/bind`.

Comment: I think a view is more like an alternative server configuration for a client set. Effectively, it is a dns virtualhost.

Comment: `rndc dumpdb --cache` won't work with bind9! Use `rndc dumpdb -cache`

Answer (score 2):

For example in named.conf:

```
options {
    ...
    dump-file       "/usr/local/etc/namedb/working/named_dump.db";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**What I had to do to view the dump.db file in 2018:**

```
sudo rndc reload
```

Reload the RNDC Cache

```
dig website.example
```

Give it data to cache

```
sudo rndc dumped -cache
```

Tell it to start listing cached items

```
cat /var/cache/bind/named_dump.db
```

View the cached DB - should display a standard response:

> ubuntu.com.       143 A   91.189.94.40

Please note that reloading doesn't appear to affect the file after you've started inputting data.

From my experience, the caching server acts just dandy but viewing the caches files will turn up empty even if the server is working in a practical perspective (e.g. dig google.com 100ms, dig google.com 1ms and 3 mins later still 1ms resolve time). Hope this helps, it's not concrete, it works and I'd appreciate corrections on this answer where appropriate.

**Note:** This applied to my Ubuntu 12.04 machine and 16.04 machine. I will test Ubuntu 18.04 soon.